# Converting MIPS to C, sltiu specifically

Tags: c, mips

I'm fairly new to MIPS, and I need to convert this MIPS code into C:

```
addi $t0, $t0, 0
sltiu $t1, $t0, 1000
beq $t1, $0, 7
sll $t1, $1, 2
```

After that it goes into some more operations, but this is the section I am having trouble translating. I think it is something along the lines of (not actual code following):

```
if (condition)
   go 7 lines down
```

But I am confused by the 1000 in the sltiu, and how to set that up. If anyone can help me out I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addi $t0, $t0, 0
    #t0 = t0 + 0;
sltiu $t1, $t0, 1000
    #t1 = (t0 < 1000) ? 1 : 0;
beq $t1, $0, 7
    #if (t1 == 0)
    #    goto foo; /* label foo is 28 bytes down the program counter */
sll $t1, $1, 2
    #t1 = $at << 2;
```

You can simplify the code to:

```
if ($t0 >= 1000)
   goto foo; /* label foo is 28 bytes down the program counter */
```

Comment: Oh I think I see now. (just saw your reply to the other, and that helped me a lot)

Comment: The sltiu sets $t1 to 1 if ($t0 < 1000), else to 0. The beq checked if t1 is zero. Therefore: we are really checking if ($t0 >= 1000) {